# Magento: performance decreases as number of cart items increases

Tags: php, oop, magento

Running Magento Enterprise 1.9, I noticed that with 20+ items in the cart the site was becoming *extremely* slow. Like, "10 seconds just to load a page" slow. As I increased this to 100 items the site became utterly unusable.

And this is not even on the cart or checkout page! It's on any page.

What can I do to mitigate this performance impact:

1) Globally, on all pages?

and

2) On the cart/checkout pages?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have APC turned on? Do you have MySQL query caching turned on?

Comment: Yes and yes. I don't believe caching is the cure but rather only covers a symptom. I see no reason why the whole cart should be loaded on every page. At the most, a cart "summary" could be loaded for the mini basket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Too many observers observing and commenting on every line of product they observe in the cart. If you don't do downloadable products or muck around with RSS, these modules can be set to active=false in their control files to turn off the modules, put the observers out to pasture and speed up the cart function.

Their overhead is phenomenal... and causes the checkout to get exponentially slower as the number of lines increases.

`app/etc/modules/Mage_Downloadable.xml` set **<active>** line to `false`.

`app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` find **<active>** line for Mage_Rss and set to `false`

The cause for this was sussed out by Rafael Kassner http://www.kassner.com.br/en/2011/01/07/magento-slow/

Standard disclaimer, YMMV, test on a dev server, etc. before unleashing on your live server.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewreply/306872/

Comment: Precisely the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you very much. I'll test this out on a dev server and report back with how it affects things.

Comment: Just a thought on this. The observer is for when an order is placed and when magento converts the quote into an order. I agree this will speed the place order function up but this is unlikey to increase the overall speed of the site and the loading of 100 products from the DB on the cart page as the observer does not get executed whilst browsing the page.

Comment: Large catalogs can also be greatly affected by products appearing in several different categories. Make sure the catalog is designed as cleanly and sensibly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Magento is a very complex and flexible system because of its MVC system and EAV database structure but as a result of this it is extremely resource hungry. You need to optimise your servers in order to handle this. Useful guides are these http://www.magentocommerce.com/whitepaper/. Consider apache, mysql, and php settings.

In addition to this you need caching systems like APC or Memcached to stop all the magento files being loaded on each request. Depending on traffic volume, concurrent users etc you will need a powerful server. Im running a dedicated quad core ubuntu server with 16GB ram and a dedicated DB server to run my store.

Regarding the 100 item cart, is this actually likely to happen? On the cart page magento will be loading all 100 products from the database which will be very intensive so if this will happen you need to look at all of the above points.

Installing APC is pretty straightforward and will have a dramatic effect straight away. Tuning your server on the other hand is more of a case of trial an error. There are many tools on the internet to help with this, I would start by using load impact tests to see how many users it can handle at once and number of requests per second etc.

There are also modules available which start to cache whole pages but not sure if this will help your 100 item cart scenario is this will be mainly database bottleneck I would assume.

Comment: Thanks Ashley, but I'm already running a 6-core dedicated server with 48GB ram, APC, and a separate DB server. I'm fairly sure this problem is a symptom of Magento's poorly optimised core code. I was looking for a solution which may offer alternatives to the "core way" of doing things.

Comment: It's likely for our customers to drop 50 items in the cart and it became fairly useless at 25. And on a reasonably heavy iron server...

Comment: I agree the code is poorly optimised but am surprised its a 10 second page load with the setup you have. The optimal setup I run is APC & Memcache. I just replicated your 100 items on my store and all pages are taking roughly 2.5 seconds and site is more than usable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with how Magento uses its attributes. It's not the db requests themselves that slow things down (around 0.06 seconds total).

I'm having the same problem and also the configurable products are very slow.

I have found some web-pages that have code that will optimize the attribute handling. (And this means more in-memory-caching of course :-)